# How to snap draggable item to limited container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have one issue creating simple block puzzle game in javascript. I'm trying to snap element to grid but I can't figure it out how to restrict drop if my element is breaking the limits of grid that is declared as droppable.

I've created a fiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/freshbm/rvr4zmtd/2/)

I use this code:

html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="element drag"> </div>
```

JS:

```
$( init );

function init() {
  $('.drag').draggable({ snap: ".cell", revert: "invalid" });
  $('.cell').droppable({
      drop: handleElementDrop
  });
}

function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) {
    dragger = ui.draggable;

    dragger.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    dragger.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    dragger.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
}
```

How to resolve issue with positioning the element in grid that prevent dropping if element goes outside the grid or if it's over non droppable cells( if we assume that we already have some dropped element in cell)?

Also I have issue with HandleElementDrop function and position of draggable, it always puts element one cell right in relation to dropped cell.

Answer (score 0):

So I made a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3q9L0nwn/) with some suggestions.

Try using the `grid` property set to a 100x100 grid instead to snapping to a `.cell` :

```
$('.drag').draggable({ snap: ".gameGrid", grid: [100,100]});
```

Also change the dimensions of the `.element` to consider the 1px of the border:

```
.cell { 
  border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
  float: left; 
  width: 99px; 
  height: 99px; 
}
```

In order for ignoring the drop if the bounds are outside the `.gameGrid` you can use the `event.position` property to write more logic on the `handleElementDrop` method.